# sorting array of complex objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, for example:

```
var a = [
 { value: 500, name: 'ccc' },
 { value: 100, name: 'bbb' },
 { value: 500, name: 'aaa' },
 { value: 300, name: 'eee' },
];
```

And I need to sort it by descending order of **value** field, **AND** if **value** field are equals -- then sort this two objects by alphabet order of field **name**.

I try something like this:

```
a.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b["value"] - a["value"] || (a["name"] > b["name"]) ? 1: -1;
});
```

But this does not result in

500,aaa
500,ccc
300,eee
100,bbb

as I would expect

Comment: What means 'not working'? Any errors?

Comment: @mplungjan The order of your results is 300, 500, 100, 500. That's not descending order of field value.

Comment: That is not my result, I just pasted the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is operator precedence, you need to parenthesize properly.

```
a.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (b["value"] - a["value"]) || ((a["name"] > b["name"]) ? 1: -1);
});
```

The logical operators have higher precedence than the ternary operator, so you need wrap the ternary expression in parentheses. I've added additional redundant parentheses to make everything explicit.

Tested result:

```
[{"value":500,"name":"aaa"},
 {"value":500,"name":"ccc"},
 {"value":300,"name":"eee"},
 {"value":100,"name":"bbb"}]
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/9Kp47/3/)

Comment: You're absolutely right. It's about operator precedence. Your suggested solution should solve the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Try to create a separate function.

```
 function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.value< b.value)
     return -1;
  if (a.value> b.value)
    return 1;
  if(a.value == b.value)
    if (a.name< b.name)
     return -1;
  if (a.name> b.name)
    return 1;

  return 0;
}

a.sort(compare);
```

Here is working example : http://jsfiddle.net/8ZUdF/

Comment: Making it a separate function has only one impact : polluting the external name space.